# Contradicting conclusions from Galois Theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory

*For those who use a different notation, $\operatorname{Hom}_F(E,E)$, which consists of all $F$-morphisms $E\to E$ below is the same as the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$.*

Let $F\subset E$ be a finite Galois extension and $M$ a subextension. Let $$^{\operatorname{id}_M\otimes_F}\operatorname{Hom}_F(E,E)=\{\operatorname{id}_M\otimes_F~\phi:\phi\in\operatorname{Hom}_F(E,E)\}.$$Then $^{\operatorname{id}_M\otimes_F}\operatorname{Hom}_F(E,E)$ is a group under compositions. There is a surjective group homomorphism $$\operatorname{Hom}_F(E,E)\to^{\operatorname{id}_M\otimes_F}\operatorname{Hom}_F(E,E)$$given by $\phi\mapsto\operatorname{id}_M\otimes_F~\phi$. Let the kernel of this map be $H$. Then $^{\operatorname{id}_M\otimes_F}\operatorname{Hom}_F(E,E)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}_F(E,E)/H$ for some normal subgroup $H\subset \operatorname{Hom}_F(E,E)$. From Galois theory $$H=\operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{Fix}(H)}(E,E)$$and that $$\operatorname{Hom}_F(E,E)/H=\operatorname{Hom}_F(E,E)/\operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{Fix}(H)}(E,E)\simeq\operatorname{Hom}_F(\operatorname{Fix}(H),\operatorname{Fix}(H))$$But as a consequence of a lemma claimed in the book *Galois Theories* by Janelidze, page 30:

> **Lemma.** We have $M\simeq \operatorname{Fix}(^{\operatorname{id}_M\otimes_F}\operatorname{Hom}_F(E,E)),$ where the right hand side of the isomorphism consists of elements $x\in M\otimes_F E$ fixed by all of $\operatorname{id}_M\otimes_F~\phi$ for $\phi\in\operatorname{Hom}_F(E,E)$.

And I would have obtained then $$\operatorname{Fix}\left(\operatorname{Hom}_F(\operatorname{Fix}(H),\operatorname{Fix}(H)\right))\simeq M$$which seems very wrong to me. Since $H$ is a normal subgroup, $F\subset\operatorname{Fix}(H)$ should be a Galois extension as well, and I should have $F$ on the right hand side instead of $M$. What goes wrong?

Comment: Your definition of this group doesn't make sense to me. It's a tensor product... in what? It's the image of $\hom_F(E,E)\to\hom_F(M,M)\otimes_F\hom_F(E,E)$? Such context is possibly crucial, the tensor relations depend on the ambient algebraic structures